# buffer "recipe" needed

Tags: buffer

I have a question, that I hope can be answered without the respondant showing off how much they know about chemistry and talking in "words of art". It's been 50 years since I tool chemistry in college, and an answer in grams, rather than moles, etc, would be appreciated. In that regard, here's the question. Starting with 4 liters of an aqueous solution of water plus 200ppm of hypochlorous acid, with a pH of between 6 & 6.2, what amounts, in grams, of NON-TOXIC buffers can be added to stabilize the pH in that range. Becoming more acid is not good for the skin, and becoming more alkaline will cause the HClO to become hypochlorite (in effect, bleach). A solution in which the buffers are solids that dissolve or precipitate out, to maintain a constant pH, would not be acceptable. Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: Honestly, I stopped reading after two sentences.

Answer (score 2):

A pH buffer at pH $6.2$ can be made in $4$ Liters water, by dissolving $\ce{104.8 g KH2PO4}$ plus $\ce{5.44 g NaOH}$. Adding $\ce{NaOH}$ will simply transform part of the dihydrogenophosphate ion into monohydrogenophosphate ion. And these two ions are not toxic.